# Two bonded 10Gb nics on an ESXi guest OS not using full bandwidth

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, bandwidth, bonding

On an ESXi guest machine, with Ubuntu 18.04 operating system, two nics connected from two difference vswitch, each of them has a separate 10Gb uplink.

I made a bonded nic from these two links with `balance-rr` and `balance-alb` modes.
When testing the bandwidth, it doesn't exceed the 10Gb (around 9.7gbps) limit for the bonded interface.

```
 bwm-ng v0.6.1 (probing every 0.500s), press 'h' for help
  input: /proc/net/dev type: rate
  \         iface                   Rx                   Tx                Total
  ==============================================================================
               lo:           0.00  b/s            0.00  b/s            0.00  b/s
           ens160:           3.82 kb/s            5.30 Gb/s            5.30 Gb/s
           ens192:          15.33 kb/s            4.35 Gb/s            4.35 Gb/s
            bond0:          19.16 kb/s            9.64 Gb/s            9.64 Gb/s
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            total:          38.31 kb/s           19.28 Gb/s           19.29 Gb/s
```

```
# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:f0:c2:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:f0:c2:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: adaptive load balancing
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: ens192
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: ens192
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:0c:29:xx:xx:xx
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: ens160
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:0c:29:xx:xx:xx
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I already tested the configuration, without using ESXi (an Ubuntu machine on bare machine), an I got a aggregated bandwidth of around 16Gbps for bond0 interface.
Also, with one nic on an ESXi guest, I can get saturate it and get a bandwidth around 10gbps.

Is there any limit on ESXi vswitch or the guest machine?

Comment: How are the vswitches configured? Are you using jumbo frames?

Comment: Also have a read of this; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469346/link-aggregation-bonding-for-bandwidth-does-not-work-when-link-aggregation-gro

Comment: vswitch configuration left as defaults: MTU 1500, Route based IP hash. I tested the config with one Nic and I can get full 10Gb bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

https://www.vmware.com/pdf/10GigE_performance.pdf

This article may help. The practical limit is 9.3Gbps for packets that use the standard MTU size because of protocol overheads.

Comment: but in general it does not solve the issue that the author states as it in general is the same to Linux and I have a similar situation and a link only answer does not solve it